# dropzone Not URL Provided and it didn't show

Tags: dropzone.js

I use dropzone in my project, but in two web pages it performs different result ,two web pages' code is similar I don't know how to solve this bug,look at the picture below. Picture 1 is the normal web page:

[image: picture 1/Normal]

Picture 2 is the abnormal web page:

[image: picture2]

the error thrown is:

> no url provided

Comment: I looks like you have an error in your `javascript` code. If there is an error, `dropzone` will look like this. Please provide code for review.

Comment: @did you try to add Dropzone.autoDiscover = false; before call dropzone?